# pandas column float to string in python

Tags: python, pandas, types

I created a new column called 'order_num' for instance

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import os

df=pandas.read_excel(os.getcwd() + r"/excel.xlsx", sheet=0, skiprows=0,)
df['order_num']=np.nan
```

and I wanted to put some value to newly created column

```
df.set_value(index, 'order_num', 'somestr')
```

and ther came error message

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'somestr'

what is the problem? I guess defalut setting of new column creation is float. and I want to change it to string

how can I do it?

Comment: You could just use `loc`.... `df.loc[index, 'order_num'] = 'somestr'`

Comment: The real question is why do you want mixed dtypes in the first place? By doing this you lose the advantage of fast value comparison, arithmetic operations etc..

Comment: I'm very new to programming and this is my first project. There is no reason to mix up dtypes. if possible and if it is more efficient, I want to make all of them to string. is that possible?

Comment: @Taewoo.Lim Yes, the answers to all the questions that you ask can be easily discovered through google.

Comment: Could do, sorry about that but I've tried at least tho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a column of type `float`, because `type(np.nan)` returns `float`.

On a mock DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],\
                  'Column2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})
```

If you create a new column and assign `np.nan` to it, the new column will be numeric:

```
df['numeric'] = np.nan
df['numeric'].dtype
```

Returns:

```
dtype('float64')
```

You could instead create a column with empty strings, i.e. `''`:

```
df['order_num'] = ''
   Column1 Column2 order_num
0        0       a          
1        1       b          
2        2       c          
3        3       d          
4        4       e          
5        5       f
```

And then add a specific string at a specific index in the column `order_num':

```
index = 0    
df = df.set_value(index, 'order_num', 'somestr')
```

This will give you the expected outcome:

```
   Column1 Column2 order_num
0        0       a   somestr
1        1       b          
2        2       c          
3        3       d          
4        4       e          
5        5       f
```